# What does "poll" in cocoa runloop means?

Tags: cocoa, runtime, core-foundation, nsrunloop, cfrunloop

In [Apple's implement](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-744.19/CFRunLoop.c) for `CFRunloop`,in function `__CFRunLoopRun` they define a local var named `pool`:

```
Boolean poll = sourceHandledThisLoop || (0ULL == timeout_context->termTSR);
```

And then they used this value like this:

```
if (!poll && (rlm->_observerMask & kCFRunLoopBeforeWaiting)) 
  __CFRunLoopDoObservers(rl, rlm, kCFRunLoopBeforeWaiting);

if (!poll && (rlm->_observerMask & kCFRunLoopAfterWaiting))  
  __CFRunLoopDoObservers(rl, rlm, kCFRunLoopAfterWaiting);
```

What does `poll` means in this context?Why `poll` is a special case in the runloop flow?